# xml is not generated in a specific format from the object in java

Tags: java, xstream

I am using `xstream` to generate the xml from the java object , below is the xml generated from the java object

```
<brokermail>
  <invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage>
    <com.absfm.ice.ioa.jms.InvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage>
      <InvoiceReference>SM/829709/0315</InvoiceReference>
      <ABSReference>IRMAR157311</ABSReference>
      <Currency>GBP</Currency>
      <InvoiceAmount>2546.0</InvoiceAmount>
      <PaidAmount>1245.0</PaidAmount>
      <BalanceAmount>0.0</BalanceAmount>
      <ValueDate>2015-05-23 20:07:20.78 IST</ValueDate>
      <Remarks>abc</Remarks>
    </com.rbsfm.ice.ioa.jms.InvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage>
    <com.rbsfm.ice.ioa.jms.InvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage>
      <InvoiceReference>SM/15</InvoiceReference>
      <ABSReference>I157311</ABSReference>
      <Currency>EUR</Currency>
      <InvoiceAmount>255546.0</InvoiceAmount>
      <PaidAmount>125545.0</PaidAmount>
      <BalanceAmount>0.0</BalanceAmount>
      <ValueDate>2015-05-23 20:07:20.78 IST</ValueDate>
      <Remarks>abERRc</Remarks>
    </com.absfm.ice.ioa.jms.InvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage>
  </invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage>
</brokermail>
```

but I want the xml to be generated in the below fashion

```
<brokermail>

  <invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage>
   <InvoiceReference>SM/829709/0315</InvoiceReference>
      <ABSReference>IRMAR157311</ABSReference>
      <Currency>GBP</Currency>
      <InvoiceAmount>2546.0</InvoiceAmount>
      <PaidAmount>1245.0</PaidAmount>
      <BalanceAmount>0.0</BalanceAmount>
      <ValueDate>2015-05-23 20:38:35.110 IST</ValueDate>
      <Remarks>abc</Remarks>
     </invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage>

     <invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage>
        <InvoiceReference>SM/15</InvoiceReference>
      <ABSReference>I157311</ABSReference>
      <Currency>EUR</Currency>
      <InvoiceAmount>255546.0</InvoiceAmount>
      <PaidAmount>125545.0</PaidAmount>
      <BalanceAmount>0.0</BalanceAmount>
      <ValueDate>2015-05-23 20:38:35.110 IST</ValueDate>
      <Remarks>abERRc</Remarks>
  </invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage>

</brokermail>
```

now as shown just above that I want the xml to be generated in the above fashion which is not happening right now. Can you please advise what changes I need to do in my below pojo to get the xml in the above fashion. Below is my pojo

```
  public class Mail {

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private  List<InvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage> invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage;

  @XStreamImplicit(itemFieldName="invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage")
    private  List<InvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage> InvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage = 
new ArrayList<InvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage>();

    public List<InvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage> getInvoiceReferenceNotificationMessages() {
        return InvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage;
    }

    public void addInvoiceReferenceNotificationMessages(List<InvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage> invoiceReferenceNotificationMessages) {
        this.invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage = invoiceReferenceNotificationMessages;
    }
```

}

and here is the main method call that is happening

Below is the main class through which below xstream is used to generate the xml.

```
ist<InvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage> invoiceReferenceNotificationMessagest = new ArrayList<InvoiceReferenceNotificationMessage>();
    invoiceReferenceNotificationMessagest.add(invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage);
    invoiceReferenceNotificationMessagest.add(invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage1);

    Mail m = new Mail();
    m.addInvoiceReferenceNotificationMessages(invoiceReferenceNotificationMessagest);




    XStream xstream = new XStream();
    xstream.alias("brokermail", Mail.class);
    xstream.processAnnotations(Mail.class);
    String abc = xstream.toXML(m);
    System.out.println(abc);
```

rite now at  xstream.processAnnotations(Mail.class); code line i am getting compliation problem indiacating add cast to xsteam please advise how to overcome from this

```
the complation error that i am getting that method processAnnotations(class<Mail>) is undefined for the type Xstream
```

folks please advise for this

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the latest version of xstream. the `processAnnotations` method was introduced in 1.3

If using maven, try

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
    <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.8</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: i have downloaded the xstream1.4.8 jar

Comment: @ndsfdddsfd try `xstream.autodetectAnnotations(true);
  `

Comment: can you please share the url from where where you havae downloaded i have downloaded from the following url http://xstream.codehaus.org/download.html and added to claass path the core one

Comment: I used maven for dependency management, though I tried your link and it works when I add it to my class path in my project. I used this [jar](https://nexus.codehaus.org/content/repositories/releases/com/thoughtworks/xstream/xstream/1.4.8/xstream-1.4.8.jar)